# how to reload only php includes inside <div>

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
 <html>
<button class="tablinks"  id="stockinboundinventory"> Inbound<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
  
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="inboundaddnewbutton()" id="addnewiteminbound" >Add new Item</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="inboundeditbutton()" id="edititeminbound" >Edit Item</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="upcomingstockbutton()" id="upcomingstockinbound" >Upcoming Stock</button>
  <button class="tablinks"  id="stockoutboundinventory">Outbound <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
  <button class="tablinks"  onclick="outbounaddnewbutton()" id="outboundnewitem" >Add new Item</button>
   <button class="tablinks" onclick="check()" id="edititemoutbound" >Edit Item</button>
   <button class="tablinks" onclick="stockavailabilitybutton()" id="stockstockavailability">Stock Report</button>
  <!--<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'historyinventory')" id="stockhistoryinventory">History</button>-->
</div>
<div id="stockinven" class="tabcontent">
  <?php


include "stockinventoryavailabilty.php"; ?>
</div>
<div id="storeinbounddiv" class="tabcontent">
  <?php


include "stockinventoryupcomingstock.php"; ?>
</div>
<div id="inboundinventory" class="tabcontent">
  <?php


include "stockinventoryinbound.php"; ?>
</div>

<div id="outboundinventory" class="tabcontent">
 <?php


include "stockinventoryoutbound.php"; ?>
</div>
<div id="historyinventory" class="tabcontent">
  <?php


include "stockinventoryhistory.php"; ?>
</div>
<div id="inboundedit" class="tabcontent">
  <?php


include "stockinboundedit.php"; ?>
</div>
<div id="outboundedittab" class="tabcontent">
  <?php


include "stockoutboundedit.php"; ?>
</div>
</html>
 <script>
      function upcomingstockbutton()
      {
           openCity(event, 'storeinbounddiv');
      }
      function check()
      {
 openCity(event, 'outboundedittab');
      }
      function stockavailabilitybutton()
      {
 openCity(event, 'stockinven');
      }
      function inboundaddnewbutton()
      {
 openCity(event, 'inboundinventory');
      }
      function inboundeditbutton()
      {
 openCity(event, 'inboundedit');

      }function outbounaddnewbutton()
      
      {
 openCity(event, 'outboundinventory');
      }
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
   
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
```

This is html and javascript code for vertical tab i like to load my php at the time clicking button instead of including while page load

Or I like to know how to reload included php file while clicking tab button instead of reloading whole page

Comment: hey, there isn't any way to load any thing with php after page's load, I think you are looking for some way to make a request to your php file and get the result and show it in you page, am I right?

Comment: What you're looking for is called AJAX. You should look into that. It's a way to dynamically load and update content depending on a certain logic. You can make any context you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69264756/refreshing-or-reloading-tab-content-using-vertical-tab-menu
This is my improved question 
Please take a look at this.