# refreshing or reloading tab content using vertical tab menu

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  display: block;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: black;
  padding: 22px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 70%;
  border-left: none;
  height: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Vertical Tabs</h2>
<p>This is code i am diplaying included php file which contains process of inserting ,deleting and updating</p>
<p>Currently after data submission or update i have to reload whole page to get current data for three tabs </p>
<p>I need to know how to refresh the selected tab php file to get the current data for selected tab witout reloading page</p>
<p>for example: after i insert data in insert tab after i select update tab it should load and show current data instead of showing old data</p>
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">insert</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">update</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">delete</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>insert</h3>
  <p>here will be my first php includes</p>
    <?php


include "insert.php"; ?>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>update</h3>
  <p>here will be my second php includes</p>
<?php


include "update.php"; ?>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>delete</h3>
  <p>here will be my third php includes</p>
<?php


include "delete.php"; ?>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

##Here is what i have##

1. My code is just displaying php file which i included with php file so it already loads the data when the tab page loads.
2. So after inserting data into database still it has old data for getting the current data i have reload whole page to get new data.
3. So i have to reload whole page every time once the process is completed.

##Here is what I needed##

1. I need to load the included page which i include with php included every time I select tab

2.If I reload only the selected tab page so i will get new data after submitting data

3. Then I will get current data to insert or delete

##Description##

1. Here in my code i used javascript for tab if you know solution for my problem in any other language like jquery it will be useful too

Comment: You need to research "AJAX"

Comment: You can try this https://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/12352/php-simple-crud-ajaxmysqli.html

Comment: Do a brief survey on `ajax` you will get to know everything, teaching it from beginning here would be difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use jQuery `load()` instead of php `include()` that will fulfil your need and it's pretty simple.

For example:

```
function somefunction(){
  $('#mydiv').load("phpfile.php");//load a php file into some division
  $('#mydiv').load("phpfile2.php", function(){//Do something after load});
}
```

You can do many things with this, like

1. Load a file on some event.
2. Load a file on time interval (every 5 seconds).
3. Load a file when some task is done or changes is made and need to be shown.

Comment: thanks for the tip i changed to jquery load but when i switching between tabs too fast its taking too much time to load
even i switched to another tab its waiting for previous tab page to load and then it starts to load current page

Comment: how to use jquery load faster for switching between tabs

Comment: There is nothing called load faster, it's you who should program it, so if you trying to load a page in some division you should have previously loaded it once the page opens. then when choose a tab the newly updated page will load.